# circles with center O and S touch each other externally at T. PT is common TaNGENT. Find PA

Tags: geometry

I have no idea how to solve this question. Please help me. Also given that $A$ and $B$ are on circle $O$ , intersect $PT$ at $P$. $C$ &$D$ are on circle $S$,intersect $PT$ At $P$. $AB=35,PC=30,CD=20. $

Comment: I have written some of the question in the body ad it was not fitting

Comment: downvoted. clearly no effort made to make the question readable ..

Comment: Please edit your question for clarity.  Is $A$ an arbitrary point in the plane?  In space?  Is $P$ an arbitrary point on the tangent line?  What does $B$ have to do with anything?

Comment: Please see body of question

Comment: You should read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: draw perpendiculars from $A, B, C, D$ to $PT$. Let's say those intersect $PT$ at points $X$ and $Y$. Now try to find similar triangles.